# I glisten in the sun

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I appear when you're exhausted,
> But not when you're frosted.
>
> In heat, I'll appear.
> If I don't, you should fear.
>
> They think I'm disgusting,
> But I just show you, you're adjusting.
>
> I'm a natural part of life,
> In dance or sickness, I am rife.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you

> [Sweat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspiration)

I appear when you're exhausted,
But not when you're frosted.

> You you are hot you sweat.

In heat, I'll appear.
If I don't, you should fear.

> When you got hot your body wets itself to cool down.

They think I'm disgusting,
But I just show you, you're adjusting.

> Sweaty socks are shown as dirty, and you sweat to get used to heat.

I'm a natural part of life,
In dance or sickness, I am rife.

> >!It is normal to sweat when you are active, when you have a fever, or just staying still.

Regarding the title

> Sweat is liquid and it reflects sun light, therefore it glistens.

Comment: Great job! You got the right answer! I'll accept it when I can.

Comment: Awesome, good riddle +1 :D

Comment: I got the idea after Jiu Jitsu practice.

Comment: Also, if you wait 20-24 hours to accept an answer you may get more view(and votes)!